# collect socket returned result in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In node.js (express.js) I can't do multiple return in an endpoint.

```
let result = {}
socket.on('receive_stream', ({data}) => {

  result = { 
     ...result,
     ...data,
  }
  // must I send it here? res.send(result)
})
res.send(result) //this is empty object
```

How can I wait and collect the stream to be finished, then only send the `result` to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let result = {}
socket.on('receive_stream', ({data}) => {

  result = { 
     ...result,
     ...data,
  }
  // have to uncommented in case always opened socket     
 // res.send(result);
})


socket.on('end', () => {
  res.send(result);
 } );
```

But  you might convert your object to string with `JSON.stringify(result)` and it works only in case closing socket. If it is always opened end event is never triggered

Comment: it is correct. but as a rule socket is always opened and end event is never triggered. In this case you should send end flag  in your stream   from your server for indicating end of sent data and process  it  in "receive_stream" event and manually triggered sending data to client when end flag is received. One emitting of 'receive_stream' event is not always received whole data from server.

Comment: BTW we used socket.io-client in our projects and it emitted socket.on('message', (data) => {}) event with whole data with always opened socket. Probably you could use the same socket client/server

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have 2 streams. So you can theoretically just pipe.

```
socket.pipe(res);
```

Or

```
socket.on('receive_stream', data => res.emit('data', data));
socket.on('end', data => res.emit('end'));
```

Comment: don't get it, yes I have socket cilent on node and another socket server on node as well, but not in the same port.

Comment: port??? you mean network port??? it is not matter. stream is abstraction under it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **in your case you must call** **req.send()** in callback of socket.

But have many ways, the problem is about your code structure design pattern, you should read posts relevant to "callback promise async await in javascript"

Comment: Sorry for this, may be I'm not explain clearly. My mind is you should explode your design pattern structure code of controller (handle req.send() ) and code of socket separate, because I saw you put them into one function.

Usually in my project, when logic code of controller is done, then handle socket after.

Sorry if i misunderstand your case.